# PersistentVolumeClaim in a namespace does not connect to a PersistentVolume

Tags: kubernetes

My PersistentVolumeClaim will not use the PersistentVolume I have prepared for it.

I have this `PersistentVolume` in `monitoring-pv.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: monitoring-volume
  labels:
    usage: monitoring
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 50Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /data/k8data/monitoring
```

After I have done

```
kubectl apply -f monitoring-pv.yaml
```

I can check that it exists with `kubectl get pv`

```
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS        CLAIM                                     STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE
monitoring-volume                          50Gi       RWO            Retain           Available                                                                        5m
```

My `PersistentVolumeClaim` in `monitoring-pvc.yaml` looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: monitoring-claim
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      usage: monitoring
```

When I do `kubectl apply -f monitoring-pvc.yaml` it gets created.

I can look at my new `PersistentVolumeClaim` with `get pvc -n monitoring`and I see

```
NAME                           STATUS    VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
monitoring-claim               Pending                                                                        manual         31s
```

When I look at my `PersistentVolume` with `kubectl get pv` I can see that it's still available:

```
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS        CLAIM                                     STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE
monitoring-volume                          50Gi       RWO            Retain           Available                                                                        16m
```

I had expected the `PersistentVolume` to be `Bound`but it isn't. When I use a ´PersistentVolumeClaim´ with the same name as this, a new `PersistentVolumeClaim` is created that is written in `/tmp` and therefore not very persistent.

When I do the same operations without a namespace for my `PersistentVolumeClaim` everything seems to work.

I'm on minikube on a Ubuntu 18.04.

What do I need to change to be able to connect the volume with the claim?

Answer (score 1):

When I reviewed my question and compared it to a working solution, I noticed that I had missed `storageClassName` that was set to `manual` in an example without a namespace that I was able to use.

My updated `PersistentVolume`now looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: monitoring-volume
  labels:
    usage: monitoring
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 50Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /data/k8data/monitoring
```

The only difference is

```
  storageClassName: manual
```

My preliminary findings is that this was the silly mistake I had done.

Answer (score -3):

Persistent Volume and Volume Claim should in same namespace. You need to add namespace: monitoring. now you can try this below code

for Persistent Volume

> **monitoring-pv.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: monitoring-volume
  labels:
    usage: monitoring
  namespace: monitoring 
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 50Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /data/k8data/monitoring
```

for Persistent volume claim

> **monitoring-pvc.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: monitoring-claim
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      usage: monitoring
```

Comment: The question is about `namespace`. This is should be the correct answer.

Comment: I don't believe this is correct. PVs are not namespaced. They're listed when you run `kubectl api-resources --namespaced=false`.

Comment: I dinged the above answer because, precisely as stated by @RobGrant and virifiable here (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/), `PersistedVolume`s and thus their matching claims, are *not* "namespaced".  The namespace attribute should not show up in the k8s manifest.yaml.